# how to transfer mongodb database from one server to another server (both of them are linux)

Tags: mongodb

So if I am hosting a MongoDB database in a Linux VM, then how can I transfer the database to another VM with the same data and structure. Also, I did some research and found out something like mongodump, but I didn't find any docs for that. So can someone give an explanation of how it works or show the docs for it

Answer (score 1):

Before **Mongodb 4.0** you can use: **db.copyDatabase()**
[db.copyDatabase()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.copyDatabase/)

After Mongodb 4.0 you must use **mongodump / mongorestore**:

```
mongodump --archive="mongodump-test-db" --db=test
```

Copy the file from one server to another and then (with database name change):

```
mongorestore --archive="mongodump-test-db" --nsFrom='test.*' --nsTo='examples.*'
```

There's a lot info here: [mongodump-example-copy-clone-database](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/#std-label-mongodump-example-copy-clone-database)